# how to test method if testing func and mocking func have different argument

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have a function and a unit test of it via mockito. I have trouble in checking the arguments. Here is the function code:

```
import API;
public class Controller {
     private Service service;
     public void testingFunction(String path, String name){
           String user = API.get(); // the function gets the userName from a API
           this.service.putInformation(path, name, user);  
     }
}
```

And here is my tester for the `testingFunction`:

```
    @Mock
    Service service;

    @InjectMocks
    Controller controller;

    private static final String TEST_USER = "userName";
    private static final String PATH = "test path";
    private static final String NAME = "test name";

    @Test
    public void valid_test() {
        controller.testingFunction(PATH, NAME);
        Mockito.verify(service).putInformation(eq(PATH), eq(NAME), eq(TEST_USER));
    }
```

However, I got the error that `Argument(s) are different! Actual invocation has different arguments`. The different argument is USER because one is TEST_USER and one is null.

It can be passed by the anyString(). However, I'm worried that the test isn't strict enough without argument check.
I'm not sure how to mock the API because it's external.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: you might need to mock the response for this function also `API.get()` can u show the actual code ?

Comment: One common way is to create SomeApiService exposing static methods of external API, and inject SomeApiService to the controller. Note that there might be a better way - spring has a ton of functionality around authentication, it is difficult to suggest sth without knowing more about your external API.

Comment: Show me the codes of `API.get();` . Ideally , it should have some way to configure which user to be returned when it is called.